# Использование Databinding LiveData в макетах без observe

Tags: java, android, binding, livedata, android-data-binding

Никак не получается заставить работать есть **Activity** на нём **Fragment**, во фрагменте есть **SwipeRefreshLayout**

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefresh"
    app:refreshing="@{vievModelList.flUpdate}">
```

**ViewModel** создается на  **Activity** и в нём есть

```
public class ViewModelList extends AndroidViewModel

public MutableLiveData<Boolean> flUpdate = new MutableLiveData<>(false);
```

во фрагменте подключаю **databinding**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = FragmentListBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    binding.setLifecycleOwner(getActivity());
    modelList = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(typeList, ViewModelList.class);
    binding.setVievModelList(modelList);
```

Но при изменении **flUpdate** ничего не происходит. Вот если добавить **observe**

```
LiveData<Boolean> statusDoc = modelList.getFlUpdate();
statusDoc.observe(this, status -> {
    binding.setVievModelList(modelList);
});
```

то всё начинает правильно работать. Подскажите, возможно заставить **databinding** работать без **observe**? Если я правильно понимаю то макет должен сам создавать у себя подписку на изменения. Возможно дело в

```
binding.setLifecycleOwner(getActivity());
```

Но я пробовал менять **getActivity()** на **this** и на **requireActivity()**, результат нулевой.

---

**Добавлено:**

Нашел вот такой способ добиться желаемого, поменял тип поля на **ObservableField**

```
public ObservableField<Boolean> flUpdate = new ObservableField<>(false);
```

Но пока не совсем понятно чем отличается **ObservableField** от **MutableLiveData**. Для этой переменной проблем нет, а вот что будет если и другие переделать не придётся ли переделывать всю логику?

---

**Добавлено:**

Согласно вот этой ссылке ничего особого делать не нужно,

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/android-data-binding-library-from-observable-fields-to-livedata-in-two-steps-690a384218f2

нужно только правильно указать владельца жизненного цикла.
Но что бы я не указывал (**this, this.getViewLifecycleOwner(), getActivity()**) (Делаю я это во фрагменте), ничего не срабатывает.

Вот если повернуть экран, например, то переменная перечитывается.

Comment: Подскажите, хотя бы в каком направлении копать. Как я понял нужно расширять класс ViewModel классом Observable. Но пока чего то не выходит

Comment: Неужели никто не знает? Может я вопрос некорректно задал? У меня всё никак не выходит добиться желаемого, поэтому все не движется дальше. Подскажите, пожалуйста, хоть что нибудь..

Comment: Я считаю, что вопрос корректный, но просто его пока мало кто увидел.

Comment: К сожалению, я в java не разбираюсь...

Answer (score 0):

судя по симптомам (работает если добавить обзервер), Вам нужна [двухсторонняя связь](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way).
попробуйте так с MutableLiveData:

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefresh"
    app:refreshing="@={vievModelList.flUpdate}">
```

обратите внимание на изменение в нотации: была односторонняя `@{}` , а стала двухсторонняя `@={}`

Comment: При попытке установить двухстороннюю связь, перестала собираться с ошибкой в сгенерированном классе bind (DataBinderMapperImpl.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
import ru.ch_mk.databinding.FragmentListBindingImpl;) Судя по ссылке что вы дали платформа не предусматривает двусторонней связи для полей типа (app:refreshing), ну или я что то не так понял.

Comment: Есть ещё какие то варианты?